Maven error :Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>JPAandHybernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>Learn-JAP-and-hybernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Learn-JAP-and-hybernate</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        **<java.version>22</java.version>**
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>**spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc<**/artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>**spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>**spring-boot-starter-web**</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>**h2**</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

console output
09:44:49.895 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils -- Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [JPAandHybernate.LearnJAPandhybernate.LearnJapAndHybernateApplicationTests]: LearnJapAndHybernateApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
09:44:50.034 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper -- Found @SpringBootConfiguration JPAandHybernate.LearnJAPandhybernate.LearnJapAndHybernateApplication for test class JPAandHybernate.LearnJAPandhybernate.LearnJapAndHybernateApplicationTests

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.4)

2024-04-20T09:44:50.934+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] J.L.LearnJapAndHybernateApplicationTests : Starting LearnJapAndHybernateApplicationTests using Java 22 with PID 71832 (started by harsha.umashankar in C:\Users\harsha.umashankar\Downloads\Learn-JAP-and-hybernate\Learn-JAP-and-hybernate)
2024-04-20T09:44:50.937+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] J.L.LearnJapAndHybernateApplicationTests : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-04-20T09:44:52.291+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2024-04-20T09:44:52.294+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-20T09:44:52.325+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 22 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2024-04-20T09:44:52.351+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2024-04-20T09:44:52.353+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-04-20T09:44:52.364+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-04-20T09:44:53.124+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-04-20T09:44:53.375+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:e71046aa-9390-404f-ac0f-f9c82623e8b7 user=SA
2024-04-20T09:44:53.378+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-04-20T09:44:53.461+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-04-20T09:44:53.560+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.4.Final
2024-04-20T09:44:53.611+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-04-20T09:44:54.021+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-04-20T09:44:54.671+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-04-20T09:44:54.678+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-04-20T09:44:54.979+05:30  WARN 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-04-20T09:44:55.902+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:e71046aa-9390-404f-ac0f-f9c82623e8b7'
2024-04-20T09:44:56.008+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [           main] J.L.LearnJapAndHybernateApplicationTests : Started LearnJapAndHybernateApplicationTests in 5.714 seconds (process running for 7.321)
WARNING: A Java agent has been loaded dynamically (C:\MyRepoHarsha\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.14.12\byte-buddy-agent-1.14.12.jar)
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is in use, please run with -XX:+EnableDynamicAgentLoading to hide this warning
WARNING: If a serviceability tool is not in use, please run with -Djdk.instrument.traceUsage for more information
WARNING: Dynamic loading of agents will be disallowed by default in a future release
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2024-04-20T09:44:57.212+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [ionShutdownHook] j.**LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit **'default'
2024-04-20T09:44:57.217+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2024-04-20T09:44:57.221+05:30  INFO 71832 --- [Learn-JAP-and-hybernate] [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

JPA EntityMAnagerFactory is getting closed. Please help to resolve this issue
I was trying to learn spring boot working on JDBC and JPA. As I am getting above error not able to proceed

Attached log contains a non anonymized path.

You need to add this dependency
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

